# Conditional for conditional in PHP

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I'm stuck in an odd situation. I'm taking dynamic boolean value from admin panel in WordPress, and with that condition of data, I need to set another conditional statement, but when in implementation I came to know that, I've never done this.

```
if( get_option('on_blog_page_too') )
   if( is_home() || is_page_template('blog.php') ) :
else
   if( is_home() ) :
```

But as you can understand I'm getting a Parse Error:

> **Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ':'...

How can I put condition over conditional statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the additional part is attached with the base conditional (the dynamic value from the back end) why not we bind them together?

```
if( ( get_option('on_blog_page_too') && is_page_template('blog.php') ) || is_home() ) :
```

So if the `option` is get, so do we need to match the `is_page_template` is `blog` or not. If the option is not set, our secondary condition is ready: only for `home` page.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Please edit your question instead of posting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yor second if don't have body, and replace : with ; something like:

```
if( get_option('on_blog_page_too') ){
    if( is_home() || is_page_template('blog.php') ){

    }
}else{
    if( is_home() );
}
```

Comment: That can be a way, but I have a huge block of items to show under each conditional, so I can't go with this way.

Answer (score 0):

replace ":" with semi-colon ";"

Comment: I think you are out of PHP :p

Comment: Ok, didn't know that.. thank you.. so i think you're missing "endif;" at the end

Comment: and if you replace ":" with ";" your code will work.. you can try it

Comment: @FirasRassas technically, that's correct so I'll give a+1 to balance your score. But OP probably didn't post all the code that goes into that if statement so simply changing to ; will not do anything except remove the parse error

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `endif;` for your inner if statements.

```
if( get_option('on_blog_page_too') )
  if( is_home() || is_page_template('blog.php') ) :
      // code here
   endif;
else
  if( is_home() ) :
    // code here
  endif;
```